# PostGIS Geography Data Changed After pg_restore

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geography-data-type, postgis-3.0, postgresql-13

Two PostGIS databases (PostGIS 3.0, PostgreSQL 13.1) were setup on two separate machines to be as close to each other as possible using a Docker image `kartoza/postgis:13.1`.

A dump of the database was taken from the first machine using

```
pg_dump --host=db1.foo.com --dbname=foo --username=postgres -Fc --file=/tmp/foo.dump
```

and then restored on the database on the second machine using

```
pg_restore --clean --dbname=foo /tmp/foo.dump
```

When we view a query result using a GUI software TablePlus, we noticed that the column named `coordinates` of type `Geography` contains values that look very different after restoring.

**Query Result on 1st Machine (pg_dump source):**

`SELECT coordinates FROM locations LIMIT 5;`

[image]

**Query Result on 2nd Machine (after pg_restore):**

`SELECT coordinates FROM locations LIMIT 5;`

[image]

However, our app that queries this database for coordinate data appears to be plotting the data correctly on a map. This makes me think that the data on both machines are the same, but stored using different representations.

**Question:** Why did the `Geography` data values in the column `coordinates` changed, and how can we restore from the dump while keeping the original data values?

---

**Update:** Tried using `-b` when performing `pg_dump`, but the problem persist.

```
pg_dump --host=db1.foo.com --dbname=foo --username=postgres -Fc -b --file=/tmp/foo.dump
```

---

**Update 2:** `\d+ locations` on both databases show the same type for `coordinates`

**1st Machine (pg_dump source):**

```
                                                                Table "public.locations"        
        Column         |         Type          | Collation | Nullable |                Default                 | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                    | integer               |           | not null | nextval('locations_id_seq'::regclass)  | plain    |              |                         
 coordinates           | geography(Point,4326) |           |          |
```

**2nd Machine (after pg_restore):**

```
                                                                Table "public.locations"
        Column         |         Type          | Collation | Nullable |                Default                 | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                    | integer               |           | not null | nextval('locations_id_seq'::regclass)  | plain    |              |                       
 coordinates           | geography(Point,4326) |           |          |                                        | main     |              |
```

Comment: It seems that your points got encoded from EWKT to WKB, either when you dumped them, or when your restored them. If you app can handle both encoding, it's normal that you do not see any changes in its behaviour. But it's somehow surprising even if the underlying data are the same.

Comment: @s.k That explains! Wonder if it is possible to avoid the conversion from EWKT to WKB at either the `pg_dump` or `pg_restore` step...

Comment: It could be a viewer "feature" too, if the 1st one is configured to display geometries/geographies using `st_asEWKT`. You can try doing the same using the psql console. After a dump+restore, we can expect the table definitions to be the same, but double check using `\d+ tablename` on both DB

Comment: @JGH You are right, `d\+ tablename` shows the same field type for the `coordinates` column (updated question to show this). I wonder why the GUI software [*TablePlus*](https://tableplus.com/) shows them differently...